# Umbraco - Add more than one RTE in Custom Grid Editor

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am creating custom grid editor and I would like to have more than one RTE inside of it. Currently, I am initializing RTE like this

```
            <div unique-id="control.$uniqueId"
                 value="control.text1"
                 grid-rte configuration="control.config.rte">
            </div>
```

This works fine for one instance of RTE. However, when I try to add 2nd or 3rd RTE in this manner, they are not initialized, instead I am getting multiline textbox.

So, how to add more than one RTE, and, is this best way to add RTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have solved the problem by adding $index. Like so:

```
                <div unique-id="control.$uniqueId + $index"
                     value="control.text1"
                     grid-rte configuration="control.config.rte">
                </div>
```

Comment: $index did not work, including some variants I tried, like control.$index. However, inspired by your answer I managed to succeed by using "control.$uniqueId+1", "control.$uniqueId+2", ...

It is possible that I am doing something wrong somewhere else so your answer is  not working in my case, but I am marking this as an accepted answer anyway.

Comment: I can confirm that the provided answer works for me - thanks @Thomas Nielsen

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <div unique-id="control.$uniqueId + $index"
>     value="control.text1"
>     grid-rte configuration="control.config.rte"> </div>
> ```

The previous answer works when the control is inside the ng-repeat directive, ie

```
<tr ng-repeat="rowData in control.tabelsData">
    <td>                    
        <div        
            unique-id="control.$uniqueId + $index"                
            value="rowData.content" 
            grid-rte configuration="rteconfig" style="border:4px solid #EB4F1C;">       
        </div>                
    </td>
</tr>
```

Otherwise yes, manually modifying the unique-id would be the answer for a known amount of multiple amount of Rich Text Editors in the editor

```
<div        
    unique-id="control.$uniqueId+1"                
    value="rowData.content" 
    grid-rte configuration="rteconfig" style="border:4px solid #EB4F1C;">       
</div>
<div        
    unique-id="control.$uniqueId+2"                
    value="rowData.content" 
    grid-rte configuration="rteconfig" style="border:4px solid #EB4F1C;">       
</div>
```